# Django tastypie PATCH error column cannot be null

Tags: python, django

I have the following resources and in my entrepreneru resources following fields exists

1. activity
2. project
3. project_url

I have used fields to get only project and project_url this works good but when I try to update using PATCH I am getting error message as

**"error_message": "Column 'activity' cannot be null"**

```
class EntrepreneurResource(ModelResource):
    founders = fields.ToManyField(FounderResource, 'founders_set', null=True, blank=True, full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = EntrepreneurProfile.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = []   # Block list view
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch']
        fields = ['project', 'project_url']
        authorization = Authorization()

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    entrepreneur = fields.ToOneField(EntrepreneurResource, 'entrepreneurprofile', null=True, blank=True, full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'role']
        list_allowed_methods = []   # Block list view
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch']
        #authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

How to resolve this?

**Update 1**

```
class EntrepreneurProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=False)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(FormLabelOptions,blank=False, related_name='activity')
    project_url = models.URLField()
```

**update 2**

```
$http({
            method: 'PATCH',
            url: '/api/v1/user/12/',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: data
        });
```

Comment: Can you post your EntrepreneurProfile model definition ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a DB/ORM issue, you need to update your model and make activity field optional.

```
activity = models.ForeignKey(FormLabelOptions,blank=False, null=True, related_name='activity')
```

Don't forget to run migration to update database schema.

Comment: tried but my existing column(active) replaced with null

Comment: So need to specify a default value if you don't want it to be nullable. Or just remove this changes and adding it to Tastypie Fields.

Comment: do you understand my point. I dont want to update all fields in model, just few fields to be modified all other fields are added once and must not change

Comment: Okay make sense, can you send me the CURL or javascript how call this web service?

Comment: Tried both put and patch ill attache my angular patch in question

Comment: Can you try this with CURL? To make sure if the error is from Tastypie or from Angular

Comment: Okay ill try give me a min

Comment: `curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH --data '{"entrepreneur": {"project": "from curl"}}' http://localhost:8000/en/api/v1/user/12/?format=json`

Comment: Why you didn't patch EntrepreneurResource directly, you have the resource_uri field in your json and you can use it ?